# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime while querying SQL

Tags: sql, jdbc

I am facing issue while querying for some data from SQL. The column datatype is varchar which has datetime stamp as part of its name, like DUMMY2_20140713.pdf.

Want to search for files between week date duration.so trying to convert part of file name to date as below:

```
select file_name,file_name 
from t_pdf_weekly_violation 
where CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(file_name, CHARINDEX('_', file_name) + 1, 8), 112) between 20150506 and 20150513;
```

But it is throwing exception..Please find stack trace below:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Arithmetic overflow
>   error converting expression to data type datetime.    at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$FetchBuffer.nextRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:4700)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.fetchBufferNext(SQLServerResultSet.java:1683)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.next(SQLServerResultSet.java:956)
>     at databaseconnection.ConnectionURL.main(ConnectionURL.java:36)

Have any one idea on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: just note, why two times `file_name` in select list in query

Comment: `CONVERT(datetime` replace with `CONVERT(int`

Comment: Piyush : taking substring of file name , so used file_name twice.

Comment: Lashane : I tried replacing datetime with int, still it is showing exception

Comment: @user3863488:- I not talking about sub-string, I mean to pointed out this code  `select file_name,file_name` in your query

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to convert substring to Datetime, just remove `CONVERT(datetime`

```
SELECT file_name,file_name 
FROM t_pdf_weekly_violation 
WHERE SUBSTRING(file_name, CHARINDEX('_', file_name) + 1, 8) between 20150506 and 20150513;
```

<kbd>[Sample SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f28e2/1)</kbd>

**Alternate Solution**

If you want to use `CONVERT(datetime`, then you have to convert your all dates

```
SELECT file_name,file_name 
    FROM t_pdf_weekly_violation 
    WHERE CONVERT(datetime,SUBSTRING(file_name, CHARINDEX('_', file_name) + 1, 8),112) 
         between CONVERT(datetime,'20150506',112) and CONVERT(datetime,'20150510',112);
```

<kbd>[Sample SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f28e2/4)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It is working when I changed return type datetime to char, like

```
SELECT file_name,file_name 
    FROM t_pdf_weekly_violation 
    WHERE CONVERT(char(8),SUBSTRING(file_name, CHARINDEX('_', file_name) + 1, 8),112) 
         between CONVERT(char(8),'20150506',112) and CONVERT(char(8),'20150510',112);
```